# youtube-dl downloads various formats

Tags: youtube, mp3, webm, youtube-dl, m4a

I'm trying to download a playlist from youtube and the songs are either downloaded in webm-format or m4a format. What I wanted was mp3. What am I doing wrong?

This is the command line i used:

`youtube-dl -i --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" https://www.youtube.com/playlist\?list\=PLYhvw_t8ea5FqXXy2w_cduTGbcXwledsP`

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with programming and doesn't belong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needs to be in the following format.

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ --extract-audio --audio-format mp3
```

you might get an error saying something about a probe, so install ffmpeg and that will fix the error.

the output will look something like the following.

```
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading js player vfls4aurX
[download] Destination: Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)-dQw4w9WgXcQ.webm
[download] 100% of 3.28MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Destination: Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)-dQw4w9WgXcQ.mp3
Deleting original file Rick Astley - Never Gonna Give You Up (Video)-dQw4w9WgXcQ.webm (pass -k to keep)
```

It will download the video, then convert it to mp3

Comment: honestly didn't expect that

Comment: nice, that worked. It seems that the problem was with the not installed ffmpeg. Thank you!